# No module named scipy.spatial.ckdtree

Tags: python, scipy, cx-freeze

I created a python file and used cs_freeze to convert it to an exe file.
When I ran the exe, I am getting the following error.

```
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 94, in <module> from .ckdtree import *
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree'
```

I checked **init**.py in spatial. It is importing from ckdtree.py. But there is no file named ckdtree in spatial folder. I have a file named "ckdtree.cp36-win32.pyd" in the same folder.

I am running on a windows 7, with 32 bit python.

I downloaded the whl file from pypi and installed scipy.

Why would I be getting this error. Why would be my installation missing ckdtree.py.

Answer (score 2):

`cKDTree` is a faster C version of `KDTree`, written in Cython. There is no file `cKDTree.py`, the `ckdtree.cp36-win32.pyd` is the binary, compiled module. You should be able to work with it as with a .py file.

How does your import look like?

`import scipy.spatial.ckdtree` ?

Try

`from scipy.spatial import ckdtree` ?